# KeyCode is not defined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, frontend

Hello guys I want to use e to get access to KeyCode but when I run it in browser it says that 'e' is not defined

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function keypress(e)
            {
                var b = eval(e.KeyCode);
                alert(b);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <input type="text" id="txt_username" onkeyup='keypress(event)'>

</html>
```

Comment: Try `e.keyCode` instead

Comment: Don't use `eval()`.

Comment: Keep in mind that `keyCode` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it will not work because you did not give a listener for your function so it will never work for a document.

Even if you fix this bug, and your code looks like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', keyPress);
function keyPress(s)
{
  var b = eval(e.KeyCode);
  alert(b);
}
```

You still won't get a positive result because you are trying to get a key code with the 'KeyCode' property. JavaScript is a camel-case language so use 'keyCode'. If you don't do this you will always get an 'undefined' result.

Thirdly, do not use eval, in this case it does nothing and is unnecessary, so delete it!

The code should look like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', onKeyPress);
function onKeyPress(s)
{
  let b = e.keyCode;
  alert(b);
}
```

Comment: In addition, as someone mentioned above, 'keypress' is already old because you just need to replace event in listener from current 'keypress' to 'keydown'.
The difference between the two is minimal and you maintain greater compatibility with browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "_it will never work for a document_", but using the DOM onevent handler works fine, as is demonstrated in the executable snippet in the question. It alerts `undefined` when you run it, which means that that function _is_ executed.

Comment: The function is executed but not on the document object, but on the input object, this was only to show as an example that the function works. It is already his choice whether listener will listen for another element from the DOM.

Comment: Thx for your help. Your Information that you gave me was sooo useful. Good Job